# Angular4 Universal Server Side Rendering would return more HTML rendered on request

Tags: javascript, angular, server-side-rendering, angular2-universal

i'm tryingo to use universal and angular4.. everything works, accessing directly via hash routes as well.. but the problem is the request always shows `<body><demo-app></demo-app></body>`

I expect to have some html tags and info inside `<demo-app></demo-app>`

Here is how I implemented that:

```
@NgModule({
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule.withServerTransition({
      appId: 'my-app-id'
    }),
    ServerModule,
    ServerTransferStateModule,
    AppModule
  ]
})

export class ServerAppModule {

  constructor(private transferState: TransferState,
  private translateService: TranslateService){
    translateService.use('en');
  }
  // Gotcha
  ngOnBootstrap = () => {
    this.transferState.inject();
  }
}


app.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
  bootstrap: ServerAppModule
}));

app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', 'src');


app.get("*", (req, res) => {
  console.time(`GET: ${req.originalUrl}`);
  res.render('../dist/index', {
    req: req,
    res: res
  });
  console.timeEnd(`GET: ${req.originalUrl}`);
});
```

My versions are "@angular/common": "^4.0.0"

Tested using https://github.com/angular/universal/blob/master/modules/ng-express-engine/src/main.ts and `import { ngExpressEngine } from '@nglibs/universal-express-engine'`

Following this discussion i could see that is a new implementation for that

- https://github.com/angular/universal/pull/681/files

Tryed to import as it suggest, but does not work (namespace does not exists)

- import { ngExpressEngine } from '@universal/ng-express-engine'

Tested with version rc.5 as suggested in this pull request.

Finally , following this link

https://github.com/angular/universal/tree/master/modules/ng-express-engine

Tested with this lib gives me same results:

`import { ngExpressEngine } from '@nguniversal/express-engine';`

At least the project is running, so i can keep coding and using it.. but looking forward to have a full server side rendering.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @mark-pieszak for you attention and support!

I could make it work using the https://github.com/clbond/angular-ssr , working with angular-material and everything.. pretty good =)

Answer (score 2):

For Angular 4+ with platform-server, use the official **`@nguniversal/express-engine`**, that other one looks like an older version of the express-engine that someone published for some reason?

The namespace is now going to be `@nguniversal` though so give that one a shot and you should be fine!

You can find **documentation** on the newest universal express-engine (for Angular 4+ and platform-server) here:

https://github.com/angular/universal/tree/master/modules/ng-express-engine

Comment: thanks for answering.. i used the `@nguniversal/express-engine` but still receiving the html not rendered on server side..  my plan is to waut for 4.1 to have fully support with angular material and try to remake the project